# Capturar primer valor de scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll

Lo que estoy haciendo:
Cuando hago escroll en mi pagina capturo la posicion del scroll. Pero ¿como haria si quisiera capturar **el primer valor** del scroll? Es decir, el primer scroll que hice, quiero guardar ese valor en una variable (y que no cambie).. Hasta ahora no puedo conseguirlo porque siempre me retorna el valor actualizado, segun la posicion donde estoy.

Answer (score 0):

Para propósitos más elaborados te diría que buscaras cómo definir la propiedad de un objeto como inmutable... pero en este caso no te compliques y **guárdalo en una variable aparte**.

Supongamos que hoy tienes un listener escuchando al scroll. No es un ejemplo muy eficiente pero sirve:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() { 
   var scrollActual = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
   console.log(scrollActual); 
});
```

Si defines a priori una variable fuera del ámbito del handler, y le das valor null o simplemente no le das valor, dentro del handler puedes saber si ha sido seteada (en cuyo caso no la tocas) o si es el primer scroll (en cuyo caso la seteas)

```
var primerScroll = null;

jQuery(window).scroll(function() { 
   var scrollActual = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
   if(primerScroll === null ) {
      primerScroll = scrollActual;
   }
   console.log(scrollActual); 
});
```

El `if` sólo se cumple la primera vez.

**Nota**

Asumí que estabas usando jQuery, voy a editar la respuesta usando vanilla pero no puedo hacerlo de inmediato.

Comment: No se moleste en editar. Si uso Jquery.Le respondere dentro de un rato porque recien voy a probar el codigo.

Comment: que significa setear?

Comment: abri otro tema explicando exactamente lo que quiero hacer y con codigo..si usted quiere puede revisarlo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/214571/ejecutar-funcion-solo-una-vez-cuando-se-hace-scroll