# Ejecutar funcion solo una vez cuando se hace scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll

Quiero que se ejecute una funcion cuando esté entre el principio y el final de una seccion. Esto ya lo hice y lo demuestro a continuacion (pero falta algo):

```
  var S1 = $( 'section:eq(0)' ).offset(  
  ).top; //OBTENGO LA POSICION VERTICAL DE LA PRIMERA SECCION
  var S2 = $( 'section:eq(1)' ).offset(  
  ).top; //OBTENGO LA POSICION VERTICAL DE LA SEGUNDA SECCION

  window.onscroll = function (  ) { 
 //CUANDO HAGO SCROLL EN LA PAGINA PASA ALGO

  //SI EL SCROLL ES MAYOR A LA SECCION NUMERO 1 Y MENOR A LA SECCION NUMERO 2, SE EJECUTA EL CODIGO
  if ( $( this ).scrollTop(  ) > S1  && $( this 
  ).scrollTop(  ) < S2 ) {
    alert( "hola" ) //A MODO DE EJEMPLO SOLO PONGO UN ALERT
  }

}
```

Mi codigo hasta ahi esta muy bien. El problema es que ese "alert" se va a ejecutar cada vez que el usuario avance un pixel con el scroll top.. O sea seran muchisimos alert, pero yo solo quiero que se ejecute uno (cuando ingrese entre los limites de la seccion uno y dos.. ¿alguien me da una mano por favor? Mi temor como siempre es estar ejecutando codigo innecesario o repetitivo. Ya lo intenté con SETTIMEOUT pero no funciona porque cada vez que se hace un nuevo scroll el settimeout se reinicia

Comment: ayuda por favor

Answer (score 1):

Podrias colocar una bandera la cual comience en 0, cuando entre el evento onscroll y tus condiciones sean verdaderas evaluas la bandera. Si la bandera es 0, entonces ejecutas tu codigo(en este caso el alert()) y  la bandera pasa a ser 1. Si se ejecuta el evento onscroll y tus condiciones son verdaderas nuevamente PERO la bandera es diferente de 0, entonces le colocas que no haga nada y listo.

```
var S1 = $( 'section:eq(0)' ).offset().top; //OBTENGO LA POSICION VERTICAL DE LA PRIMERA SECCION
var S2 = $( 'section:eq(1)' ).offset().top; //OBTENGO LA POSICION VERTICAL DE LA SEGUNDA SECCION
var bandera = 0;
window.onscroll = function () { //CUANDO HAGO SCROLL EN LA PAGINA PASA ALGO
//SI EL SCROLL ES MAYOR A LA SECCION NUMERO 1 Y MENOR A LA SECCION NUMERO 2, SE EJECUTA EL CODIGO
if ( $( this ).scrollTop(  ) > S1  && $(this).scrollTop() < S2 ) {
    if(bandera==0){
      alert( "hola" ) //A MODO DE EJEMPLO SOLO PONGO UN ALERT
      bandera=1;
    }else{
    //No hacemos nada
    }

} 
else{ //tampoco hacemos nada
  }
}
```